# Junit works individually in IntelliJ but fails from Maven

Tags: java, maven, junit

I have some junit test cases within a test class. It runs fine when you run the file as a whole from IntelliJ. 
But when I run the maven build, it fails.

```
TestCase Code Snippet {
doReturn(DummyObject with values).when(springRepo).call()
executeTest()
}
```

We have a TestUtil which has some static methods to create DummyObject at runtime based on different input keys. What I see that Junit always runs testcases sequentialy and there are no parallel test cases run unless specified.

Now, Dummy object is not null, but few of the internal data is null only from Maven run. What could be the issue?

Comment: Without an full error output impossible to say?

Comment: You can check or upgrade the maven-surefire-plugin to the last version, maybe there is a fix for an specific issue with a previous version of the plugin or a previous version of junit. I encountered before some difference between intellij and maven during test execution but i fixed it easily by upgrading my plugins to the last version.